# Crafter Security for delivery

Tags: crafter-cms

This online doc explains how to configure security (LDAP and SSO) for Studio:

https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/system-administrators/security/configure-studio-security.html

I assume the functionalities are provided by the `craftercms/commons/security` subsystem. Can this be used by Crafter Delivery to provide LDAP and/or SSO integrations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SAML 2.0 is supported by Crafter Engine, see this guide: https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/site-administrators/engine/engine-site-security-guide.html

Very similar to how it's done in Studio, only simpler because there is no role mapping.